Android Studio - не применяется градиент к кнопке
пытаюсь сделать градиентную кнопку в android studio, но она всё равно дефолтного фиолетового цвета. Всё уже перепробовал, и rebuild и clean, ничего не помогает. Подскажите в чем может заключаться дело
Код кнопки:
<Button 
 android:id="@+id/reg_button" 
 android:layout_width="410dp" 
 android:layout_height="90dp" 
 android:background="@drawable/button_back" 
 android:text="@string/reg_button" 
 android:textSize="27sp" 
 android:textStyle="bold" 
 android:layout_marginBottom="100dp" 
 />

Код файла в папке drawable с градиентом:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
 <item> 
 <shape> 
 <gradient android:angle="120" 
 android:type="linear" 
 android:startColor="#ffa602" 
 android:centerColor="#ff168d" 
 android:endColor="#8227ff"> 
 </gradient> 
 <corners android:radius="100dp" /> 
 </shape> 
</item> 
</selector>


После перехода на AndroidX как раньше не работает, но вот так должно работать.
<Button 
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/button_back"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    ...
 />

Где namespace app определен как xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Помогла строчка  вместо  в файле themes.xml, но спасибо)
